# How can I call what I have in Static Method from MainActivity in Android

Tags: java, android, json, static, android-asynctask

I have this class and a problem with the simple Static {} method:

```
 package com.example.tabletapp1.dummy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

public class DummyContent {

    public static List<DummyItem> ITEMS = new ArrayList<DummyItem>();
    public static Map<String, DummyItem> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, DummyItem>();
    public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> stireList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    static {   /////// THIS FUNCTION
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        String url = "http://kosalis.beclenar.ro/stiri.txt";

        // JSON Node names
        String TAG_STIRE = "stire";
        String TAG_ID = "ID";
        String TAG_NUME = "Nume";
        String TAG_DESCRIERE = "Descriere";
        String TAG_POZA = "Poza";
        String TAG_CORP_STIRE_HTML = "Corp_stire_html";

        // contacts JSONArray
        JSONArray news = null;

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
            news = json.getJSONArray(TAG_STIRE);

            // looping through All Contacts
            for (int i = 0; i < news.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = news.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NUME);
                String description = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIERE);
                String poza = c.getString(TAG_POZA);
                String body_html = c.getString(TAG_CORP_STIRE_HTML);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_NUME, name);
                map.put(TAG_DESCRIERE, description);
                map.put(TAG_POZA, poza);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                stireList.add(map);
                addItem(new DummyItem(id, name, description, poza, body_html));

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error2", TAG_CORP_STIRE_HTML);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void addItem(DummyItem item) {
        ITEMS.add(item);
        ITEM_MAP.put(item.id, item);
    }

    public static class DummyItem {
        public String id;
        public String title;
        public String description;
        public String content;
        public String photo;

        public DummyItem(String id, String title, String description,
                String photo, String content) {
            this.id = id;
            this.title = title;
            this.description = description;
            this.photo = photo;
            this.content = content;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return title;
        }
    }
}
```

But I have no Idea how to do what is in the static { } function from MainActivity.
I would like to call an asynctask from my mainactivity because every time my app starts, the UI freezes, and I'm sure it's because of that static functions which creates a JSONPArser class:

```
    package com.example.tabletapp1.dummy;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {
    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "ISO-8859-2"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

And I have another question:
Lets say I have a AsyncTask, and in doInBackground() I call the JSONParser class, is that going to freeze the UI or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to replace `static {` with `static void staticMethod() {`. Then you can call it with `DummyContent.staticMethod()`.

edit: @Mah makes a good point about the multiple questions. Please let me know if you create a new one and I can move part of my answer to it for you.

As for Asynctask, it is indeed good for jobs like these since anything done in `doInBackground()` will not block the UI thread. For me there was somewhat of a learning curve with it but I've found it to be a very useful class. To use the example below you would call `new myAsyncTask().execute(url)`

```
class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... url) {
        // This will receive the String you passed into it and return a boolean to onPostExecute()
        // Put all your CPU intensive stuff here

        // publishProgress can be used update the UI thread
        Integer progress = 1;
        publishProgress(progress);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... doInBackgroundResult) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(doInBackgroundResult);
        // Anything done here can update the UI but will block
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean doInBackgroundResult) {
        super.onPostExecute(doInBackgroundResult);
        // Runs after doInBackground finishes
        // Anything done here will block the UI
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you, It works fine. One more thing : the method must be public so I could acces it from MainActivity() (to help others).

Answer (score 2):

You didn't define a static method, you defined a static initializer; it gets automatically run when the object is instantiated. Make it an actual method (with the static keyword) and you will be able to call it.

As to your other question: it's unrelated to the first; create a separate question for it.

Comment: This means that if I make an asynctask in MainActivity and in doInBackfround() I call the MyStaticFunction() , it would work without freezing the UI ? Thank in advice!

Comment: No, it means nothing one way or the other regarding freezing the UI. You asked two unrelated questions, but you must create a second post for the second question. I answered the question you listed first / took up most of your post with. Create a new question post, not a comment on this one, for your new question... but as long as the code is not being run in the UI thread, it shouldn't typically freeze/block the UI.